# How to find an element that may be in multiple xpath locations?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, xpath

In a Web page having the following xpaths.

```
xpath1 = By.xpath(".//*[@id='gamepackage-game-information']/article/div/div[2]/span")).getText();

xpath2 = By.xpath(".//*[@id='gamepackage-game-information']/article/div/div[1]/figure/figcaption/div")).getText();
```

Some webpages having `xpath1` & Some webpages having `xpath2`

How to get the text using if condition in Selenium Webdriver?

Comment: Would you please, share the HTML that represent the 2 controls and a sample text to search for.

Answer (score 1):

In xpath creation, we can use logical OR condition.

```
xpath1 = By.xpath(".//*[@id='gamepackage-game-information']/article/div/div[2]/span" | .//*[@id='gamepackage-game-information']/article/div/div[1]/figure/figcaption/div)).getText();
```

I hope it solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use try cache block.

```
String text = null;
try{
   text = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath1)).getText();
}catch(NoSuchElementException ex){
   text = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath2)).getText();
}
```

Hope that helps.
P.S: This is just a pseudo code.

Comment: That would catch ALL exceptions now and in the future and could lead to very hard to diagnose bugs due to other exceptions being caught by it.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant I understand that part. Its just a pseudo code, so its upto the user to fill in what exception to be used.

Comment: @Ravi Kindly select the best answer.

Comment: @mayur that makes no sense.  the real code wold use the exception approach, correct?

Comment: @MichaelDurrant Yes actual code will use the exception approach. I get what you are saying. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like

```
# pseudo code
String text = null;
text1 = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpath1)).getText();
text2 = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpath2)).getText();
if text1 <> '' or text2 <> '' then  # NOTE: I don't know java syntax!
  code...
```

You might have to use `findElements` (note plural) and check for the array size being zero (that is if `findElement` raises an error).  `findElements` tends to get around that by just returning an empty array.

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath1)) is null, it will throw exception and execution will not proceed.

Comment: Yes, updated for both queries to use findElements instead of findElement

Comment: When you use findElements, it will return list of elements. So, you will have to use index. Example, in Java driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpath2)).get(0).getText()

Answer (score 0):

In our software testing company we encountered a similar situation and below worked for us.

```
if(driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath1)).isdisplayed){
return driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath1)).getText();
}
else
return driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath2)).getText();
```